# gridEX checkbox filter shows text value when not selected

Tags: gridex

I am filtering a checkbox column with FilterEditType.CheckBox. Whenever I click on the filter it works fine, but when the filter column loses focus it shows the textual representation of the checkbox. In my case right now it is a 1 or a 0 and I know I can use CheckBoxTrueValue or CheckBoxFalseValue to change it to something else.

I need the filter to either show a checkbox(checked or not checked) or nothing at all while it has the filter applied. Does anyone know how to do this I couldn't find a property that seemed to fit.